# Working with openpyxl. making a list out of a column

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am working with a big excel file.
I am using

```
wb = load_workbook(filename='my_file.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
```

I don't want to alter the worksheet in any way. I just want to take data from several columns and work with them.
My understanding is that I can't just call a column and use `.tolist()` because all the values are stored in excel.

Comment: `ws.columns` will return you a tuple of tuples so you don't really need a list.

Comment: That just gives me columns in the form `<Cell Sheet1.A1>` and so on. But how can I take values info from column A, put them into a list and work with them? `ws['A1'].value` gives with the info I am looking for. I guess the only way then if to make a for loop that would go through all the rows in a column and append them into a list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment here's one thing you can do:

```
mylist = []
for col in ws.iter_cols():
    mylist.append(col.value)
```

edit: due to API change.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This is not working for now, since ws.columns is a generator. It should be like:
`for col in ws.columns.next():`

Comment: I got this error: TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 14):

Bernie's answer, I think, was for a slightly older version of OpenPyxl. `Worksheet.columns` no longer returns tuples but rather, is a generator. The new way to access a column is `Worksheet['AlphabetLetter']`.

So the rewritten code is:

```
mylist = []
for col in ws['A']:
     mylist.append(col.value)
```

Comment: ```mylist = [c.value for c in ws['A']]```